# Update Scaffold-Properties in nested CupertinoPageScaffold in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-cupertino

How can I update some properties of the roots scaffold in a child widget(page).

Here is a snippet from my root scaffold.

```
CupertinoPageScaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
          state.resizeToAvoidBottomInsets, //update this here
      child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
            onTap: onTap,
            items: widget.items,
          ),
          tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            return StatusBarPadding(child: _tabs[index]);
          }),
    ),
```

The [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html#material.Scaffold.4) say, I should add a listener to avoid a nested scaffold (e.g. to update resizeToAvoidBottomInset).
However, this does only work for one page per tab. When I nest tabs, I can't access them directly anymore.

I tried two solutions which I will explain in the follow (+problems):

### Solution 1: Provider

I used a Provider to keep track of a global Navbar State:

```
class NavbarState extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _resizeBottom;

  NavbarState(this._resizeBottom);

  get resizeBottom => _resizeBottom;

  void setResizeBottom(bool state) {
    _resizeBottom = state;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then In my Pages I set the state in the initState-Method with `BlocProvider.of<NavbarState>(context).setResizeBottom(val)` (respective for dispose).

This has **2 problems**:

1. Calling notifyListeners triggers a setState in the consumer and you can't call setState in the initState method.
2. I have to declare this in every initState and dispose method.

### Solution 2: Bloc

Once again I have a global state, but it does not have to inherit from `ChangeNotifier`. I track the state with a `NavbarBloc`-class.

Then I can add an event in the `onGenerateRoute` method. This is more handy then the provider approach, because there is just one place where I manage this state.

However, there is still a big **problem**:

When I navigate back, the `onGenerateRoute` Method does not get called and hence the state is not getting updated.

### What the easiest solution would be

At least from an app-developer perspective it would be nice if I could just ask for the the current widget which is sitting in the active navigator.

### Example of a Navbar

Here is an illustration of 3 navigators for the given cupertinotabscaffold.
[image: 3 Navigators while the 2nd is active]

The middle "stack" is active and the topmost widget is seen on the screen. Thus, currently the resize param should be false. On navigating between the stacks (tapping navigation icon), the resize parameter should adjust. Furthermore, on navigating in between a single stack (push, pop) should also adjust the resize param (E.g. on a pop the param should be set to true).

I couldn't find anything like that. Thus I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

For setting the state how about a setter as a callback to `onTap`?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var values = [
    [true, false],
    [false, true],
  ];

  int stackIndex = 0;
  bool _resizeToAvoidBottomInsets = true;
  set _resizeToAvoidButtomInsets(bool value) => setState(() {
        print("set _resizeToAvoidBottomInsets = $value");
        _resizeToAvoidBottomInsets = value;
      });

  void handleTap(int i) {
    print("tapped: $i");
    _resizeToAvoidBottomInsets = values[stackIndex][i];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: _resizeToAvoidBottomInsets,
      child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
        tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.wb_sunny)),
          ],
          onTap: handleTap,
        ),
        tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                  middle: Text('Page 1 of tab $index'),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: CupertinoButton(
                    child: Text(
                      'resizeToAvoidBottomInsets: $_resizeToAvoidBottomInsets',
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // set state and increment stack index before push
                      stackIndex++;
                      _resizeToAvoidButtomInsets = values[stackIndex][0];
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        CupertinoPageRoute<void>(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                              navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                                middle: Text('Page 2 of tab $index'),
                              ),
                              child: Center(
                                child: CupertinoButton(
                                    child: Text(
                                      'resizeToAvoidBottomInsets: $_resizeToAvoidBottomInsets',
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      // set state and decrement stack index before pop
                                      stackIndex--;
                                      _resizeToAvoidButtomInsets =
                                          values[stackIndex][0];
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    }),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite solve the problem. As it only changes the resize parameter when you switch between navigation icons. I adjusted my question to illustrate an example  configuration of navigator-stacks.

Comment: I've edited my answer in response to your edits. Let me know if this achieves the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for the effort :) The problem remains though. In your example you have two pages only and can only navigate by pressing onto the button. 1. Imagine you have a larger project, then you have to modify every single page (about 50 pages). 2. You ignore the fact, that you can navigate through swipeBack(iOS)/navBack(Android) as well and have no control about that. You could wrap every Page with a WillPopScope, but 1. remains.

Answer (score 0):

So I implemented a solution for the given problem. I don't think this is very smooth, but at least one can abstract the scaffold-properties from each single page.

I use a bloc for that as already mentioned in the question-solution-try-2.

The bloc emits a state `MyScaffoldState` which contains a `ScaffoldProperties` attribute. For this toy example I implemented it as  follows:

```
class ScaffoldProperties {
  bool resizeBottom;
  String title;

  ScaffoldProperties({this.resizeBottom = false, required this.title});

  ScaffoldProperties copyWith({ScaffoldProperties? state}) {
    return ScaffoldProperties(
      resizeBottom: state?.resizeBottom ?? resizeBottom,
      title: state?.title ?? title,
    );
  }
}
```

You could add any scaffold-property to this class.

The main work happens in my `MultiTabScaffold` class. This class takes the parameters

```
List<Widget> pages;
List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items;
Route<dynamic>? Function(RouteSettings)? onGenerateRoute;
List<NavigatorObserver> navigatorObservers
```

And most importantly

```
Function<ScaffoldProperties> getScaffoldPropertiesFromRouteName(String? route);
```

The class wraps the necessary Scaffolds around the pages. Additionally, it uses a `BlocBuilder` and thus can use the `ScaffoldProperties` of the current state.

The `getScaffoldPropertiesFromRouteName` Method takes a route and returns a ScaffoldProperties-Instance. Thus all title, resizeProperties,... have to be collected here.

To update the current state (or emit events to the bloc), I had to modify a few points.

1. **onGenerateRoute**: After generating the route (pushing to navigator), the `ScaffoldProperties` of the current page have to be emitted (with usage of the `getScaffoldPropertiesFromRouteName` Function)
2. **WillPopScope**: Also after popping the page, I emit an event with the properties of the page below.
3. **Initial Value**: Initially, when you open the app, neither onGenerateRoute nor willpop will be called. Thus, you have to have a different handling for the initial route '/' of every Navigator.

I have a toy [example](https://github.com/Babwenbiber/multi_tab_scaffold) fully implemented.

This feels like a lot of work for such a simple use case, but I couldn't find a simpler way to do this. If there is one, please let me know.